# SQL LINESTRING() versus multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, gps

I am storing GPS coordinates of route with `LINESTRING()` in one row. When I want to work with that data, I need to use another functions, i.e. `X()`, `Y()`, `ASTEXT()`, `GEOMFROMTEXT()`, etc.

I was thinking, if its not better to have another table, where one GPS coordinate will be stored in one row. So for each route I will have N rows in that table.

My question is, what is your opinion, if it will be faster, or its better to store GPS coordinates of the routes with `LINESTRING()` in one row per each route?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would definitely create a new table with one lat/lon pair per row. This is the classic normalized database format.

Be sure you include a column allowing you to put the points of each route in the proper order. For example,

```
 route_id int   (fk to route table)
 point_seq int   (counts the points in the route 0,1,2, etc)
 lat float
 lon float
```

In this design proposal the table's primary key is the compound of `(route_id, point_seq)`

You may want to create a compound index `(lat, lon, route_id, point_seq)` to allow [efficient coverage](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=661727) of location queries.

`LINESTRING` and friends are part of the [OpenGIS extension to MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html). There are some mapping systems using that extension. But, it has the key disadvantage (right now) that compound spatial/nonspatial indexes aren't available. That slows lots of spatial querying.

Comment: Yes, that I understand. My question is, why then is used `LINESTRING()` to store GPS coordinates of route?